# How to add a new entry into a GWT DataGrid?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I tried to find any solution for adding new entry into a GWT DataGrid widget, but it was unsuccessful.

I have the following code for a custom DataGrid widget:

```
/**
 * Custom DataGridWidget with asynchronous data transferring.
 */
public class DataGridWidget implements EntryPoint {

    /* Path to UI template */
    @UiTemplate("ui/DataGridWidget.ui.xml")
    /* Interface for using UiBinder */
    interface IDataGridWidget extends UiBinder<Widget, DataGridWidget> {
    }

    /* Instance of IDataGridWidget interface for next initialization of this widget */
    private static IDataGridWidget dataGridWidget = GWT.create(IDataGridWidget.class);

    /* Instance of service class for getting data from server in async mode */
    protected static GettingServiceAsync gettingService = GWT.create(GettingService.class);

    /* DataGrid */
    @UiField(provided=true)
    DataGrid<Contact> dataGrid;

    /* "Add entry" button */
    @UiField(provided=true)
    Button bAdd;

    /**
     * Entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {
         /* Initialization of dataGrid */
        dataGrid = new DataGrid<Contact>();

        /* Create name column */
        TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                return contact.name;
            }
        };

        /* Create address column. */
        TextColumn<Contact> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public String getValue(Contact contact) {
                return contact.address;
            }
        };

        /* Add the columns */
        table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
        table.addColumn(addressColumn, "Address");

        /* Create a data provider */
        CustomDataProvider dataProvider = new CustomDataProvider();

        /* Connect the dataGrid to the data provider. */
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(dataGrid);

        /* Initialization of the "Add entry" button */
        bAdd = new Button("Add entry", new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                /* SOME CODE FOR ADDING A NEW ENTRY */
            }
        });

        /* Initialization of dataGridWidget */
        initWidget(dataGridWidget.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

}
```

and I have the following code for a custom AsyncDataProvider:

```
/**
 * Custom AsyncDataProvider for transferring data from the server.
 */
protected class CustomDataProvider extends AsyncDataProvider<Contact> {

    @Override
    protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<Contact> display) {
        /* Get a new Range */
        final Range range = display.getVisibleRange();

        /* Start of range */
        final int start = range.getStart();

        /* How much entries we will get */
        int length = range.getLength();

        /* AsyncCallback for retreiveing entries form the server */
        gettingService.getRangeContacts(start, length, new AsyncCallback<List<Contact>>() {
            public void onSuccess(List<Contact> result) {
                /* Updating data into the dataGrid */
                updateRowData(start, result);
            }
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Window.alert("Error transferring data from the server");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Maybe anyone have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: -1 for poorly worded question. You need to explain a bit further what you are trying to achieve using code sample. What exactly is failing in the code?

Comment: Ok. Use case: User press button, named "Add entry", then DataGrid reach up on a one empty-field entry. Thats all. I do not think it necessary to give a [trivial example](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html) of DataGrid from GWT javadoc. Thanks.

Comment: I consider this is impossible without dirty coding. Goodbye, GWT. I go to the [play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) with the [CRUD](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/crud) module.

Comment: If you understood DataGrid you will find that this question is complete. Whoever who flagged -1 does not understand the question, and therefore finds the question incomplete. The question is complete and comprehensive and no further illustration is needed.